# JMX mBeans structure with Tomcat (Embedded vs Standalone)

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I am currently working with Spring Boot (1.5.9) with embedded tomcat (8.5.23.0) and accessing JMX mBean's.
When I run 'jconsole' I find that the mBean name is "Tomcat" and the structure inside is:
[jconsole with Embedded Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMpxf.png)

But when I launch a **standalone** Tomcat (8.5.23.0, same version) the mBean name is "Catalina" and the structure inside is different from embedded Tomcat: [jconsole with standalone Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEDSw.png)

The documentation at: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/monitoring.html does not help, it is only about remote connecting to JMX mBeans, not the structure and names which is what I need.

Is there any d**ocumentation about Tomcat JMX exposed beans** (names, structure, content) **both for standalone Tomcat and for embedded (Spring Boot) instances**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same occurss for Spring Boot 1.5.10 and embedded Tomcat 8.5.27

Comment: It would be great to be able to determine which is being used at runtime so that you can query the right beans. Did you ever find an answer to this?